# Installed Ubuntu on Windows 10 - Windows not loading unless UEFI

Tags: dual-boot

So I got a Lenovo laptop with Windows 10, installed alongside, so the grub menu comes up with options including Ubuntu and Windows.

When I try selecting Windows 10 I get a black screen error in Windows Boot Manager that says
File: \Boot\BCD has errors
Status: 0xc000000e
Info: The boot configuration data is missing

I checked the script for windows, says set root= 'hdo,gpt3'

I can boot into windows if in the BIOS I set boot order to UEFI only. This makes it boot directly to Windows without a selection.

I can only boot into Ubuntu if I change Bios to UEFI/Legacy, but when I get the Grub screen and try Windows I get that error.

So obviously installed wrong and would like to fix.

I installed boot-repair and got this report:
Check http://paste2.org/tugzUwbV

I suspect the Grub menu option is pointing to the wrong location for the \Boot\BCD?

Should I reinstall Ubuntu in efi mode?

Thanks for any advice!
(16.04 LTS in 64 bit mode, Lenovo Z51)

Comment: Oops, your paste link gives: "page not found".

Comment: Sorry, maybe the page timed out? It's not really an issue anymore since I'm not using windows. If I do I just change BIOS to boot in UEFI mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done much on the BIOS Ubuntu install, it is best just to reinstall it in UEFI mode.  DO NOT select "reinstall" from the install media, that wipes the disk of everything.  Select the "do something else", and select the partitions, and format them to wipe the old installation.  The actual differences of the two installs are minor, like getting the grub-efi-amd package instead of the grub-pc and mounting the efi partition at /boot/efi (fstab modification), but easier just to reinstall.